# preg_match or similar to get value from a string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match

I am not good with `preg_match` or similar functions which are not deprecated.

Here are 2 strings:

1. `/Cluster-Computers-c-10.html`
2. `/Mega-Clusters-c-15_32.html`

I would to find out:

In number 1 example, how to get the value between `-c-` and `.html` (the value in the example is 10). The value is always an integer (numeric)

In number 2 example, how to get the value between `-c-` and `.html` (the value in the example is `15_32`) . The value is always an integer seperated by `_`

Basically what I want to do is check if a string has either `c-10.html` or `c-15_32.html` and get the value and pass it to the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
preg_match('/-c-(\d+(?:_\d+)?)\.html$/i',$str);
```

Explanation:

```
-c-     : A literal -c-
(       : Beginning of capturing group
 \d+    : one or more digits, that is a number
 (?:    : Beginning of a non-capturing group
   _\d+ : _ followed by a number
 )      : End of non-capturing group
 ?      : Makes the last group optional
)       : End of capturing group
\.      : . is a metacharacter to match any char (expect newline) to match 
          a literal . you need to escape it.
html    : a literal html
$       : End anchor. Without it the above pattern will match any part 
          of the input string not just the end.
```

[**See it**](http://www.ideone.com/akStV)

Comment: Thanks for that. I just wanted to confirm that if the url string has parameters such as mydomain.com/Cluster-Computers-c-10.html?action=blah

Comment: Also, just wanted to confirm that $matches will always have an array with 2 strings? or can it be more or less than 2 ever? I am asking because I need to assign $path = $matches[1]; and want to make sure it will always be same.

Answer (score 3):

```
preg_match('~-c-(.*?)\.html$~', $str, $matches)
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I just wanted to confirm that if the url string has parameters such as mydomain.com/Cluster-Computers-c-10.html?action=blah

Comment: Also, just wanted to confirm that $matches will always have an array with 2 strings? or can it be more or less than 2 ever? I am asking because I need to assign $path = $matches[1]; and want to make sure it will always be same.

Comment: @Eddy: it can be 0 or 2 items there. 0 - when nothing matched, 2 - when something matched. So put `if (isset($matches[1])) { $path = ...; } else { nothing matched }`

Answer (score 1):

```
/-c-(\d+(?:_\d+)?)\.html$/i
```

`-c-` look for -c-
`(\d+(?:_\d+)?)` match number or number-underscore-number
`\.html` a period and trailing html
`$` force it to match the end of the line
`i` case-insensitive match

Example:

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: text/plain');
  $t = Array(
    '1) /Cluster-Computers-c-10.html',
    '2) /Mega-Clusters-c-15_32.html'
  );
  foreach ($t as $test){
    $_ = null;
    if (preg_match('/-c-(\d+(?:_\d+)?)\.html$/i',$test,$_))
      var_dump($_);
    echo "\r\n";
  }
?>
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "-c-10.html"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "10"
}

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(13) "-c-15_32.html"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "15_32"
}
```

Working Code: http://www.ideone.com/B70AQ

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I see would be:

```
preg_match( '/-c-([^.]+)\.html/i', $url, $matches );
var_dump( $matches );
```

Comment: `.` in the `[]` don't need to be escaped.